# compilation problem with tif image converted to eps

Tags: errors, conversion

I use a microscope which only allows saving images as `.tiff`.
Thus, I need to convert them into `.eps` using an online converter.
The compilation crashes and I don't understand the reason.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[2.5x optical magnification]{\label{fig:olymp316L2.5x} \includegraphics[scale=0.11]{Olympus/316L/2pt5xavecechelle.eps}}
    \subfigure[10x optical magnification]{\label{fig:olymp316L10x} \includegraphics[scale=0.11]{Olympus/316L/10x.eps}}\hfill
      \subfigure[10x optical magnification]{\label{fig:olymp316L10xbiz} \includegraphics[scale=0.11]{Olympus/316L/10xparticulesbizarres2b.eps}}\hfill
    \caption{Optical magnifications of 316L stainless steel}
    \label{fig:olympus316L}
\end{figure}
```

And here is the error message:

> pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file /compile/Olympus/316L/10x-eps-converted-to.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Since you are using `pdflatex` why don't you convert the `tif` image to `png`?

Comment: without more information not possible to say why the conversion failed but as pdftex can not include eps files natively converting from tif to eps which then needs to be converted again is not optimal if you converted the tif to png or jpg or pdf then it could be included directly

Comment: To have a good image quality

Comment: the image quality is not changed by converting to EPS it  just causes a following conversion (that failed in your case) from EPS to a format that pdflatex can include

Comment: I thought I would loos image quality by using .png or .jpg

Comment: the tiff file is a bitmap so you can encode the identical bitmap in png format. EPS _can_ encode scalable vector images but a conversion from tiff to eps will not do that it will just be a bitmap wrapped as an EPS

Comment: thank you very much! I didnt understand because I had other .eps "native" files that compilated perfectly

Comment: It should work but there is something specific with the eps you generated that made its conversion to pdf fail, and we can not really help with that (and it may be off topic for this site)  but if you can directly convert the tiff to a format that pdflatex understands the problem goes away....